# css Background positioning of sprite

Tags: css, sprite

Is the `background-position` css property used to indicated where in the element should the image be displayed (like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-position)) or what part of the image should be displayed (like when using sprites) ?

In my instance i have a div of let's say `300px` width, i want the image to be shown in the right part of that element so normally i just added a `center right` to my background declaration, though now my image is a spirit so how can i control the coordinate of the image that i want to display ?
 Seems to me that this background property act in 2 different way.. Am i missing something ?

Comment: Is it possible for you to recreate this in jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

If the place where you want to put element of the sprite is larger then the element then you need to put white space (trasnparent) around it. And you can't use keywords like center, you need to use pixels, because you will center whole sprite and not your element.

Using sprites is like using window where background is larger then background image so you need to position the window (actually you position the background).

Answer (score 0):

If your container is larger than the background sprite image part you want to display then the other part of image will also be displayed. Better use Sprite cow to generate sprite it will give you the css for different parts of sprite image

http://www.spritecow.com/

Comment: Ok thanks that is a very usefull app indeed.. Though i still dont get it the css background property really does have 2 different behavior ?